# Sailsjs : authentication controller not called

Tags: javascript, node.js, authentication, sails.js, access-token

I'm following this `https://thesabbir.com/how-to-use-json-web-token-authentication-with-sails-js/`
but when i try to access to `http://localhost:1337/auth?email=test@gmail.com&password=test` in POSTMAN
 i get 404 not found because the controller AuthControllers.js not called any idea please ?

Comment: Do you send a GET request in POSTMAN?

Comment: @AlexeyPedyashev yes

Comment: In that tutorial I don't see any mentions about setting up a route for your AuthController. Just check if you have like the following: module.exports.routes = {

  /** Auth */
  'POST /auth': 'AuthController.index'

}

and also make a POST request not a GET from postman